# Bibliography does not print - TexShop - Document type - Article

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes

I have been trying unsuccessfully for a while to include the Bibliography along with \footcite. I was able to improvise with the \footcite but when it comes to the Bibliography, I just can't get it to print.

I would really appreciate, a suggestion with fixing this, or what I could do different, even it it means taking up a complete new reference approach.

```
%-----Tex Document:

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm,bindingoffset=0cm} % or letter or a5paper or ... etc
\usepackage{layout} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test_temp.bib}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\newcounter{savepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\includepdf[pages={1}]{Cover_PDF_T.pdf}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\contentsname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\newpage
\section*{List Of Abbreviations}
\label{sec:abbr}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:abbr}}
ID      - Identification\\
\newpage
\setcounter{savepage}{\arabic{page}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\footfullcite{Cp. New, Guy, Old, Guy J ; Old, Guy K ( 2008)}.
These are the only qoutes \footcite{Cp. Old, Guy (2005)}
\section{Motivation}
\lipsum
\section{Research Questions}
\lipsum
\section{Research Method}
\lipsum
\section{Conceptual Framework}
The conceptual framework which is followed is that of a narrative type with graphical aids provided to help clarify in a simpler manner. 
\subsection{Theoretical Framework}
The theoretical framework below explains the aspects which are covered in this thesis.
\subsubsection{Framework1}
\lipsum 
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=200pt]{xyz}
\caption{xyz}
\label{xyz}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\subsubsection{Framework2}
\lipsum
\section{Thesis Structure}
\lipsum
\begin{enumerate}
\item Abstract
\item Introduction
\item Research Methodology
\item Conceptual Framework
\item Analysis of Qualitative and Quantitative data
\item Summary and Implications.
\end{enumerate}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{secti on}{\refname}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{\thesavepage}
\printbibliography
%\layout
\end{document}

%---Bibtex
@article{Cp. New, Guy, Old, Guy J ; Old, Guy K ( 2008),
title = " future research directions ",
journal = "International Journal of Production Economics ",
volume = "112",
number = "2",
pages = "510 - 520",
year = "2008",
note = "Special Section",
issn = "0925-5273",
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/",
url = "http://www.direct.com/article/pii/S0925",
author = "New, Guy, Old, Guy J ; Old, Guy K",
keywords = "Academic literature review",
keywords = "Classification framework ",
abstract = "Academic research into"
}

@online{Cp. Old, Guy (2005), 
  title = {The History of Technology},
  url = {http://www.journal.com/articles/view?111},
  abstract = {Identification has been around for decades. Learn how it evolved from its roots in  technology.},
  urldate = {2015-05-04},
  year = {2005}, 
  month = {January 16},
  journal = {Journal},
  author = {Cp. Old, Guy (2005)},
  date = {2005-01},
}
```

Comment: Did you run `biber`? I'm pretty sure you will be getting errors: look at the console output. Your keys look very odd. I don't think you should use weird characters in them e.g. commas, spaces, full stops, brackets, semicolons. Stick to letters, numbers, underscores, hyphens and colons. (Probably some other things are OK - see the documentation but I'm sure things like commas and spaces will be problems.)

Comment: Also, your authors are specified incorrectly: `New, Guy and Old, Guy J. and Old, Guy K` would be correct. Probably the title should be capitalised and you may need to delete the spaces in the `pages` field. `month` as `January 16` is wrong. `month` should be `jan`, if you do it this way, and `day` should be `16`. Or drop these and use `date`.

Comment: Hi cfr, I did run biber in Texshop by Shift + Cmd + B, if that is what you mean.

Comment: I should have been much clearer. The format required is - LastName_Complete, FirstName_Complete Initial_Only. Also the Bibtex are grabs from the online article Bibtex which I modified a bit for this example.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I thought it didn't print at all?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't not print at all. When I used apacite, earlier, it used to print the bibliography fine. But I need a different format along with footcite for my report, hence I decided to use Bibtex, but it doesn't work in my example

Comment: You have to run `biber` instead of `bibtex`. Please try to minimise your code a bit. Nobody can compile it as it stands, even.

Comment: I am using TexShop on Mac, I can I run biber as  you mentioned it. Do I run latex before and after it as well. Thank you

Comment: Yes. Before and after. But you also have to correct the `.bib` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimised version of your example with a corrected `.bib` file and the results:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{new-guy2008,
    title = " Future Research Directions ",
    journal = "International Journal of Production Economics ",
    volume = "112",
    number = "2",
    pages = "510 - 520",
    year = "2008",
    note = "Special Section",
    issn = "0925-5273",
    doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/",
    url = "http://www.direct.com/article/pii/S0925",
    author = "New, Guy and Old, Guy J  and Old, Guy K",
    keywords = "Academic literature review",
    keywords = "Classification framework ",
    abstract = "Academic research into"
  }

  @online{old-guy2005,
    title = {The History of Technology},
    url = {http://www.journal.com/articles/view?111},
    abstract = {Identification has been around for decades. Learn how it evolved from its roots in  technology.},
    urldate = {2015-05-04},
    year = {2005},
    month = jan,
    day = 16,
    journal = {Journal},
    author = {Old, Guy},
    date = {2005-01-16},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none}
\begin{document}
  Some text\footfullcite{old-guy2005,new-guy2008}.
  These are the only qoutes \footcite{old-guy2005}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Notes:

- The identification keys you use in the `.bib` file ***cannot include weird characters***. That means no commas, spaces, full-stops, brackets etc.
- Multiple authors must be separated by `and` in the `author` field.
- Titles should be capitalised as appropriate.

Ill-formed keys explain why you get no bibliography at all. Incorrect author specifications explain why you would get errors anyway (and why you might not get any bibliography at all, depending).

The bibkey you use is just an identifier - it does not get printed in your final document (although it will show up temporarily before `biber` is run). It does not need and, in most cases, cannot look like a formatted citation key. The same goes for the various fields you fill in. The way you specify the author, for example, does not look the way you want that field to be printed in your final document. Regardless of the desired format, you specify the data in the `.bib` file in the same way. (Ideally, anyway, and in most cases.)

So, for example,

```
  author = {Cp. Old, Guy (2005)},
```

is wrong. It does not give the author's details in the required format and it tries to give stuff which is not part of that information at all. Corrected:

```
  author = {Old, Guy},
```

assuming the person's name is 'Guy Old'.

Similarly, you cannot have, for example:

```
@article{Cp. New, Guy, Old, Guy J ; Old, Guy K ( 2008),
```

because this is not acceptable as a bibkey. Something like:

```
@article{new-old-old2008,
```

is one alternative.

Output from the above code then gives:

[image: bibliography]

## EDIT

To change the format of citations and the bibliography, you give `biblatex` options and, if necessary, use additional customisation commands. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{new-guy2008,
    title = " Future Research Directions ",
    journal = "International Journal of Production Economics ",
    volume = "112",
    number = "2",
    pages = "510 - 520",
    year = "2008",
    note = "Special Section",
    issn = "0925-5273",
    doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/",
    url = "http://www.direct.com/article/pii/S0925",
    author = "New, Guy and Old, Guy J  and Old, Guy K",
    keywords = "Academic literature review",
    keywords = "Classification framework ",
    abstract = "Academic research into"
  }

  @online{old-guy2005,
    title = {The History of Technology},
    url = {http://www.journal.com/articles/view?111},
    abstract = {Identification has been around for decades. Learn how it evolved from its roots in  technology.},
    urldate = {2015-05-04},
    year = {2005},
    month = jan,
    day = 16,
    journal = {Journal},
    author = {Old, Guy},
    date = {2005-01-16},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-ibid, autocite=footnote, firstinits=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
  Some text\autocite{old-guy2005,new-guy2008}.
  These are the only qoutes \autocite{old-guy2005}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

will produce:

[image: bibliography variant]

Notice that both citations and the list of references are formatted differently. (Well, I've also used `\autocite{}` this time - you can experiment to see the differences.) But the `.bib` file is exactly the same.

Note, too, that the bibkeys do not appear anywhere in the final document.

Comment: Thanks cfr. But the reason why I was forced to use those bibkey is because I need the footnote which shows it in the format - Cp. Old, Guy (2005). Can I change the footcite to show this text, even if I used the modified keys as in your corrections.   Additionally, I need to also print the bibliography without any number.

Comment: This is the formatting for references with footnotes included

Citing Examples:

Footnotes for literal and analogous quotations:
2 Simchi-Levi et al. (2003), pp. 1–2 
3 Cp. Picot; Böhme (1999), pp. 5–8 

Footnote literal quotation: 
Picot; Böhme (1999), p. 37

Footnote analogous quotation: 
Cp. Picot; Böhme (1999), p. 37

Entry in the bibliography: 
Picot, Arnold; Böhme, Markus (1999): Controlling in dezentralen Unterneh- mensstrukturen, München, 1999 
 
Foot notes for repetitions:

1 Cp. Picot (1999), p. 5 

2 Ibid., p. 8
 
3 Cp. ibid., pp. 48–51

Comment: @vsp You ***cannot*** use those bibkeys. You can control what `\footcite` etc. produce. But if you use those bibkeys, you will never get a bibliography. Did you not notice the errors or that they keys are printed in bold in your document? Printing the keys is `biblatex`'s equivalent of `bibtex`'s `??`. It makes it easier to figure out what is undefined.

Comment: @vsp I don't understand the formatting you are describing in terms of literal and analogous quotations. (Surely all quotations are 'literal' by definition?) But you get the results you want by telling `biblatex` which style to use and, if necessary, using further customisation. The bibkeys are irrelevant to the formatting. They are *just* identifiers. All they do is tell `biber` *which* bibliography entry you want it to use.

Comment: @vsp Why have you asked for `numeric` if you don't want a numeric style?

Comment: @vsp See edit. Not sure, but probably you want e.g. `\autocites[1-23]{simchi-levi2003}[Cp.][]{picot-YYYY}[5-8]{bohme1999}` or something. That is, you need to use pre-notes and post-notes appropriately to format your citations.

Comment: mentioning numeric was my mistake. I have set it to nyt now. For the references if a literal reference is used in the text of the document, the foot has just the author and year, but if it is analogous, as in not literally but has part of the text or is in an interpreted sentence, the requirement is that Cp. is appended at the beginning of the footnote and only the author(s)(;) and year is mentioned with page no.. As to your earlier comment, I did notice the errors initially, but I was not sure if it had to do with the special characters. Log only said that citations were not found.

Comment: Thanks cfr, I believe with the pre/post notes I am pretty close to what I am looking for. But I would like to get rid of the and between authors in the references and replace it with a ;. Thanks

Comment: @vsp You can try `\renewcommand\finallistdelim{;\space}`. But if you do this, how will readers know when the `;` separates two different entries as opposed to two different authors? Just the lack of a date in the second case? It makes it much harder to individuate entries.